# How to convert from an EasyLyte RJ-12 connector to and RS-232 serial connector

Tags: cable, rs232, com

I have a device with an RJ-12 connector, I need connect to a computer by RS-232. This is document of device:

> Computer Connection:
>
> The EasyLyte systems can be interfaced with an external computer by means of an RS-232 serial interface. Potential users will require the following information:
>
> EasyLyte RS-232 Protocol
>
> Transmission Rate 1200 baud
> Bit Configuration 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, no parity
>
> This interface requires a serial cable from Medica. A telephone-style connector at one end of this cable plugs into the receptacle labeled on the back of the EasyLyte. The other end of the cable is a female D-Sub 9 pin connector with the following pinouts:
>
> Pin #2 TxD
>
> Pin #3 RxD
>
> Pin #7 CTS
>
> Pin #8 RTS
>
> Pin #5 Signal Ground

RS-232 has 9 pin, RJ-12 has 6 pin. I don't understand this field so I don't know which pin of RJ-12 is connected to which pin of RS-232?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pinout chart I found online:

[image: RS-232 to RJ-12 and other connector pinout chart.]

A [Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&tbm=isch&q=RJ12%20to%20Rs232&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbmsDA5OzhAhWwc98KHZP8AbwQBQjHASgA&biw=1294&bih=744&dpr=2#imgrc=Zl5yWHC9SqovEM:) shows other similar charts.

Comment: For 8P8C it would be sort-of standard (Cisco/Yost cable, and it's got the whole 8 pins connected unlike this graphic claims), but for 6P6C I strongly suspect it's custom for every device...

Comment: Hi @grawity,I also think like you but the machine's documentation does not describe this parameter, so bad :(